# What is the best practice of fuzzy search (like '%aaa%' in MySQL) in Elasticsearch 6.8

Tags: elasticsearch, wildcard

Background: I use Mysql and there are millions data, each line have twenty columns, we have some complex
search and some column use fuzzy match, such as `username like '%aaa%'`, it can't use mysql index unless remove the first `%`, but we need fuzzy match to do search like Satckoverflow search, i also checked Mysql `fulltext index`, but it doesn't support complex search whthin one sql if using other index.

My solution: add Elasticsearch as our search engine, insert data into Mysql and Es and search data only in Elasticsearch

I checked Elasticsearch fuzzy search, `wildcard` works, but many people don't suggest use `*` in the word beginning, it will make search very slow.

For example: username: 'John_Snow'

`wildcard` works but may very slow

```
GET /user/_search
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "username": "*hn*"
    }
  }
}
```

`match_phrase` doesn't work seems only work on Tokenizer like phrase 'John Snow'

```
{
  "query": {
      "match_phrase":{
      "dbName": "hn"
      }
  }
}
```

My question: Is there any better solution to do complex query that contains fuzzy match like '%no%' or '%hn_Sn%'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You can use [ngram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) that first breaks text down into
> words whenever it encounters one of a list of specified characters,
> then it emits N-grams of each word of the specified length.

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query, and results.

**Index Mapping:**

```
     {
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "my_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
                }
            },
            "tokenizer": {
                "my_tokenizer": {
                    "type": "ngram",
                    "min_gram": 2,
                    "max_gram": 10,
                    "token_chars": [
                        "letter",
                        "digit"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "max_ngram_diff": 50
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "title": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
                "search_analyzer": "standard"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Analyze API**

```
POST/ _analyze

{
  "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
  "text": "John_Snow"
}
```

The tokens are :

```
   {
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "Jo",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 2,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "Joh",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 3,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 1
        },
        {
            "token": "John",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 4,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 2
        },
        {
            "token": "oh",
            "start_offset": 1,
            "end_offset": 3,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 3
        },
        {
            "token": "ohn",
            "start_offset": 1,
            "end_offset": 4,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 4
        },
        {
            "token": "hn",
            "start_offset": 2,
            "end_offset": 4,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 5
        },
        {
            "token": "Sn",
            "start_offset": 5,
            "end_offset": 7,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 6
        },
        {
            "token": "Sno",
            "start_offset": 5,
            "end_offset": 8,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 7
        },
        {
            "token": "Snow",
            "start_offset": 5,
            "end_offset": 9,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 8
        },
        {
            "token": "no",
            "start_offset": 6,
            "end_offset": 8,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 9
        },
        {
            "token": "now",
            "start_offset": 6,
            "end_offset": 9,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 10
        },
        {
            "token": "ow",
            "start_offset": 7,
            "end_offset": 9,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 11
        }
    ]
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "title":"John_Snow"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "title" : "hn"
        }
    }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "test",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.2876821,
                "_source": {
                    "title": "John_Snow"
                }
            }
        ]
```

**Another search query**

```
{
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "title" : "ohr"
        }
    }
}
```

The above search query shows no result

Comment: Hi @Bhavya, thanks for your answer, `tokenizer ` `ngram` works, i will test millions data query performence later

Comment: @KDFinal glad it worked for you :) Can you please accept and upvote my answer, as well, as it helped you resolve your query :)

Comment: Hi @Bhavya, I have another question, `n-gram` tokenizer will seperate word by its `min_gram `,`max_gram `, for example `name="John_Snow"` and set `min_gram=2, max_gram=2`, if i search "hn", "John_Snow" will return, but when i search "ohr", it will also return  "John_Snow" , like `MySQL` `like '%ohr%'`, 'ohr' should return empty result.

Do you have any idea to change tokenizer strategy?

Comment: @KDFinal please go through my updated index mapping, and now if you search ```ohr``` it will give empty result (as it should be). Let me know if you have further queries on this :)

Comment: after added `"search_analyzer": "standard"`, all data can't be found, can you help to check that, very thanks!

Comment: @KDFinal Can you please tell, querying on which data you not able to get result?

Comment: mapping config: ```"tableName" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            },
            "analyzer" : "my_analyzer",
            "search_analyzer" : "standard"
          },```

           query:
```GET /assets/table/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "tableName" : "bmtj"
        }
    }
}```

          result:
```
 "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221570/discussion-between-bhavya-gupta-and-kd-final).

Comment: Thanks @Bhavya, it works, i missed some config in my json

Comment: Great @KDFinal :) Thank u for accepting and upvoting my answer :)