# Elastic Search substring search

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, wildcard

I need to implement search by substring. It is supposed to work the same like “CTRL + F” that highlight a word if its substring matches it.

The search is going to be performed by two fields only:

- Name - no more than 255 chars
- Id - no more than 200 chars

However, number of records going to be pretty large about a million.

So far I’m using querystring search by keywords wrapped with wildcards but it will definitely lead to performance problems later on once number of records will start growing.

Do you have any suggestions how would I do more performance wise solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Searching with leading [wildcards](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html#query-dsl-wildcard-query) is going to be extremely slow on a large index**

> Avoid beginning patterns with * or ?. This can increase the iterations
> needed to find matching terms and slow search performance.

As written in documentation wildcards queries are very slow.
Better to use ngram strategy if you want it to be fast at query time. If you want to search by partial match, word prefix, or any substring match it is better to use [n-gram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html), which will improve the full-text search.

The ngram tokenizer first breaks text down into words whenever it encounters one of a list of specified characters, then it emits N-grams of each word of the specified length.

**Please go through this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63912517/10348758), that includes a working example for a partial match using ngrams**

Comment: @Petr Savchenko did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you 

Comment: Thanks @Bhavya, it does look like n-gram tokenizer is gonna be better solution. I have also found [wildcard field type](https://www.elastic.co/blog/find-strings-within-strings-faster-with-the-new-elasticsearch-wildcard-field) which is another alternative. I am keen to compare those two